# Working with Wagtail on Replit, facing "common-passwords.txt.gz" error

Tags: python, django, wagtail, replit

So, I am trying to pip install Wagtail in a Python repl. But when I start a project and try to create a superuser, I get the following issue: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.cache/pip/pool/f7/e7/0e/common-passwords.txt.gz'

It seems Wagtail cannot seem to find the common-passwords.txt.gz file for some reason.

[UPDATE]

As requested, here's the full stack trace of the error.

```
~/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/mysite$ python3 manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'runner'): 
Email address: 
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 236, in __init__
    with gzip.open(password_list_path, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 58, in open
    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 173, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.cache/pip/pool/f7/e7/0e/common-passwords.txt.gz'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 87, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 182, in handle
    validate_password(password2, self.UserModel(**fake_user_data))
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 50, in validate_password
    password_validators = get_default_password_validators()
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 22, in get_default_password_validators
    return get_password_validators(settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS)
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 36, in get_password_validators
    validators.append(klass(**validator.get("OPTIONS", {})))
  File "/home/runner/NecessaryOffbeatEvents/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 239, in __init__
    with open(password_list_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.cache/pip/pool/f7/e7/0e/common-passwords.txt.gz'
```

Any way I can solve this?

Thanks in advance,,,

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Done. Please check the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

I finally fixed this problem, by manually creating the missing "common-passwords.txt.gz" file in the mentioned directory.